# Proof of Theorem 22.2, Munkres' Topology

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, quotient-spaces

I think the proof does not show that $f$ is continuous when it wants to show that $f$ is a quotient map if $g$ is a quotient map. Am I correct?

[image]

Comment: The proof shows continuity 4 lines above. Why would it prove it again there?

Comment: @N.S. Thank you. I see it now. Because if $g$ is a quotient map, then $g$ is continuous. By the first paragraph, $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"$f$ is continuous" was already shown, see the last sentence of the previous paragraph. This is still true, so the only thing left to show that for "$g$ quotient implies $f$ quotient" is what is claimed: surjectivity of $f$ and $f^{-1}[O]$ open in $Y$ implies $O$ open in $Z$. The other implication of continuity of $f$ is always true by the previous, because $g$ quotient implies $g$ continuous and so $f$ continuous as well. That implication was already established so can be used.

Comment: Is the surjectivity of $f$ necessary in your proof? Because I read a solution for the exercises of this session. If they want to prove some function $p:X\to Y$ is a quotient map, besides proving the continuity of $p$, they would set $U$ in $Y$ such that $p^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$. Then they show $U$ is open in $Y$. You can see the solution for 22.2 (a) here http://www.math.colostate.edu/~clayton/courses/500/500_2.pdf

Comment: @user398843 Not really. But surjectiveness is part of the definition of a quotient map and so it must be checked to be fulfilled. The surjectiveness of $p$ is used in defining $g$ from $f$.

Comment: It's interesting to know that the surjectivity of $p$ is used in defining $g$ from $f$. Because I usually think the surjectivity of $p$ is not important and I don't know why do people put it on the definition of quotient map. Can you tell me how do we define $g$ from $f$?

Comment: @user398843 We define $f$ from $g$ of course, sorry: see Munkres'  text above: given $g: X \to Z$, we want to define $f: Y \to Z$. Pick $y \in Y$. First we use that $p$ is surjective and find $x \in X$ with $p(x) = y$, and we define $f(y) = g(x)$. If we had picked another $x' \in X$ with $p(x') = y$, we get the same point, as $x'$ is also in the same fibre of $p$ and $g$ is constant on fibres of $p$. But we need at least one such point, so $p$ needs to be surjective.